# How to deny changes of source code by others in github?

Tags: git, github

I have my source code uploaded in gitHub and I want to be the only one who can change it.

How to tell this to GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

No one can change your code until you allow.
They can make pull request and if you want you can merge it with your branch. 
And you can use bitbucket for privacy.

Comment: That's also correct. But keep in mind that they will still able to see your code until you make your repo private.

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy commercial plans to do that in GitHub. Otherwise your repo will be public.

As an alternative, you can use Bitbucket, they offer free private repos.

You can see github private repos [here](https://github.com/pricing).

Comment: A public repo only means the public can read it. Write access is still limited.

Comment: @sleske I'm aware of that. That's already mentioned at other answer.